# Echart: How to set mark area to fill sections in xAxis

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a problem with marking area: i need to be able to select a bar area based on xAxis, for example from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2, etc. But when i try to provide options for bar like

```
[{xAxis: 0, itemStyle: {color: red}},{xAxis: 1}]
```

it marks an area from a middle of xAxis area with an index of 0 to a middle of xAxis area with an index of 1. Is there a way to make it mark from start of an area to an end. Currently i managed to do so only with x option in pixels:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-echart-markarea-ksj31?file=/src/index.js:714-726

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I can't imagine a method that would cover your requirements. It seems there is no such but nothing prevents to do it ourselves, see below.

When call function with `join = true` markedArea will calc as range from first to last.

```js
calcMarkAreaByBarIndex(myChart, join = true, [4, 9])
```

When call function with `join = false` markedArea will calc for each bar.

```
calcMarkAreaByBarIndex(myChart, join = true, [4, 5, 6, 9])
```

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
 
  var option = {
      tooltip: {},
      xAxis: {
      data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
    },
      yAxis: {},
      series: [
       {
         id: 'myBar',
         name: 'Series',
         type: 'bar',
         data: [11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 110, 123, 113, 134, 93, 109],
          markArea: {
           data: [
             [{x: 184},{x: 216}],
             [{x: 224},{x: 256}],
             ]
       },
      },
   ]
  };
     
  myChart.setOption(option);
  
  function calcMarkAreaByBarIndex(chartInstance, join = false, barIdx){
  var series = chartInstance.getModel().getSeriesByType('bar');
  var seriesData = series.map((s, idx) => s.getData())[0];
    var barNum = seriesData.count();
    var barCoors = [];
    var layout = idx => seriesData.getItemLayout(idx);
    
  for(var i = 0; i < barNum; i++){
     if(!barIdx.includes(i)) continue;
     barCoors.push([
       { x: layout(i).x },
        { x: layout(i).x + layout(i).width },
      ])
    }
    
    if(join){
     return [
       [
         { x: barCoors[0][0].x },
         { x: barCoors[barCoors.length - 1][1].x }
        ]
      ]
    } else {
     return barCoors
    }
  }
  
  var markedAreas = {
   series: {
     id: 'myBar',
      markArea: {
       data: calcMarkAreaByBarIndex(myChart, join = true, [4,9])
      }
     }
   };
  
  myChart.setOption(markedAreas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.7.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, that worked for me:
Basically, you need to manually set yAxis's max props, add another xAxis, make it invisible, create a custom series with type 'bar' and set xAxisIndex to 1:

```
data: [maxYaxisValue,maxYaxisValue...], //length === xAxis.data.length
type: 'bar',
barWidth: '100%',
color: transparent,
xAxisIndex: 1,
```

And style a bar by index with background color and borderWidth
You can check the working example here
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-echart-markarea-m0mgq?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It's the same like my answer but less flexible. Also extra xAxis not required if series not difference.

Comment: I dont see how it's the same. It's less complicated and does not have a large amount of math under the hood. For my taste it's the better solution just because of a native nature of it. You dont have to worry about resizing and other stuff, but you do you.