# Does a line chart with markarea take 'x' or 'xAxis'?

Tags: echarts

Looking at [the documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-lines.markArea.data.0.x), the x position of the area is defined in `markArea.data.0.x`. But all the examples I found use (including [this official example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections)) specify it in `markArea.data[0].xAxis`. I'm new to echarts and not a very experienced JS developer so maybe I'm just missing something basic here but, why the apparent discrepancy?

Playing around in the example code, it seems both work, though `x` looks like an offset in pixels, whereas `xAxis` corresponds to a value on the x-axis. Guessing the documentation just hasn't been updated...

Comment: Documentation doesn't even mention `xAxis`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right the docs not contains complete information and some parts a bit outdated. It confuses while studying but in the next time you already know the architecture and docs will be used only just for remember option name. It's normal for opensource and limited resources because instead fix docs better fix bugs.

About question. You can define the markArea coordinates with a different ways and if you not found solution in docs for target series please try to use options in other series, they can be similar.

For example some weeks ago I made the more easest way to define filled area: [Echart: How to set mark area to fill sections in xAxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495988/echart-how-to-set-mark-area-to-fill-sections-in-xaxis)

If it's not helped for you please mention me there, I will try to find solution.

**Update**:

1. Take a look that [data format](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/search?l=HTML&q=MarkArea) can be used for `markArea`
2. Pay attention on [detailed description](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.markArea.data) `markArea` format